# How to specify the filename during download over HTTP

Tags: javascript, php, amazon-s3

I currently store my woocommerce product files on S3 in the following format:

```
/bucket/{product_id}.zip
```

When a customer clicks the download link in their customer dashboard the element is as follows:

```
<a href="https://url/1234.zip">Download Product Name</a>
```

This downloads the file into their downloads folder as 1234.zip

I would like to be able to pass some values to the request so that the filename can be downloaded as {param1}-{param2}.zip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
<a href="https://url/1234.zip" download=`${param1}-${param2}.zip`>Download Product Name</a>
```

Refer: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#attr-download

Note:

> download only works for same-origin URLs, or the blob: and data:
> schemes. How browsers treat downloads varies by browser, user
> settings, and other factors. The user may be prompted before a
> download starts, or the file may be saved automatically, or it may
> open automatically, either in an external application or in the
> browser itself. If the Content-Disposition header has different
> information from the download attribute, resulting behavior may
> differ: If the header specifies a filename, it takes priority over a
> filename specified in the download attribute. If the header specifies
> a disposition of inline, Chrome and Firefox prioritize the attribute
> and treat it as a download. Old Firefox versions (before 82)
> prioritize the header and will display the content inline.

Comment: Wow, that simple. Brilliant, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

When they click a button to download the file, you can add the HTML5 attribute "download" where you can set the default filename.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#attr-download

<a href="https://url/1234.zip" download={`${param1}-${param2}.zip`}>Download Product Name